# Evitar que al pegar texto se añada en un span - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

tengo un div con `contenteditable`, mi problema es que cuando pego un texto este se añade pero dentro de un span con el `style` de donde lo copie. Lo que quiero es que cuando yo pegue un texto este no se añada en un `span` ni  conserve el estilo de donde lo copie.

Ejemplo:

```css
.text {
   background: rgb(30,30,30);
   color: whitesmoke;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" contenteditable="true">
    Peguen un texto aquí
</div>
```

Disculpen si mi pregunta no fue clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo a través de javascript. Previenes el comportamiento por defecto de pegar el texto con formato, conviertes el contenido a texto plano, y finalmente lo insertas.

```js
editor = document.querySelector(".text")
editor.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

```css
.text {
   background: rgb(30,30,30);
   color: whitesmoke;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" contenteditable="true">
    Peguen un texto aquí
</div>
```

Comment: Preferiblemente cambié el `document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);` por `document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);` ya que si por ejemplo pego un texto con `<h1>Hola Mundo</h1>` dentro del elemento se añadiría un h1.

Comment: Perfecto, lo que sea más conveniente para lo que buscas. Yo solo te di la idea.